# Downgrade wordpress plugin to use older version of php

Tags: wordpress, background-image

I developed a website in wordpress and used several plugins. One of the plugin was http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/background-manager/

Every thing was working fine on my machine. But as i get uploaded it to client server. the whole site stuck due to lower version of PHP. This plugin requires `PHP 5.3` and on server we have `PHP 5.2`. Since its a shared server, we can't upgrade its PHP.

Then i look into the code of this plugin it was using `PHP 5.3` feature `namespaces`. Is there any way to downgrade this plugin that it will work with `PHP 5.2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really tricky problem, and of course, it's really, really bad practice to use old code for plugins as they may have fixed security vulnerabilities or other serious problems.  It would be better for you to move the site to a server with more up to date PHP.

Having given that important warning, you can, however, browse to the tags directory in the plugin repository and extract the files you want for the previous version.  Plugin history is public and always maintained.

For instance, for the plugin you mentioned, you can visit the SVN part of the plugin repository at:
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/background-manager/

You'll find the previous versions there under the "tags" folder, named after their versions.